# How to make cpu-friendly infinite loop for mono when detached from terminal

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, servicestack

I've been using this code in my self-hosted ServiceStack app for sleeping MainThread:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

but it doesn't work when application is detached from terminal (for example is started by start-stop-daemon) because of this bug: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=689976

As a fast workaround I have changed code to:

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

I have seen that Thread.Sleep shouldn't be used this way.

How do I properly freeze main thread when app is detached from terminal and running on mono?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on linux (or other **posix** system), instead of using **Console.ReadKey** you should listen to a termination or kill signal, using the [Mono.Posix](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix/) library, as shown in the [example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux) on the ServiceStack wiki:

```
        UnixSignal [] signals = new UnixSignal[] { 
            new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGINT), 
            new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGTERM), 
        };

        // Wait for a unix signal
        for (bool exit = false; !exit; )
        {
            int id = UnixSignal.WaitAny(signals);

            if (id >= 0 && id < signals.Length)
            {
                if (signals[id].IsSet) exit = true;
            }
        }
```